# How to fetch information from web page chain wise(solving captcha)?

Tags: python, web-scraping

I have to go to  [here](https://ipindiaservices.gov.in/PublicSearch/)

Here I have to choose  applicant name = “ltd”

But here before submitting the page, I have to solve a captcha. How to fetch the next page's information(application number, application title, date, application status etc.....) in an excel format using web scrapping?

---------------- Running the following script, getting error -----

```
import csv
import json
from time import sleep, time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver import DesiredCapabilities
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.webdriver import WebDriver
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException


def save_to_csv(data: list) -> None:
    with open(file='ipindiaservices.csv', mode='a', encoding="utf-8") as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f, lineterminator='\n')
        writer.writerow([*data])

def start_from_page(page_number: int, driver: WebDriver) -> None:
    driver.execute_script(
    f"""
    document.querySelector('button.next').value = {page_number}; 
    document.querySelector('button.next').click();
    """
    )

def titles_validation(driver: WebDriver) -> None:
    """replace empty title name with '_'"""
    driver.execute_script(
        """
        let titles = document.querySelectorAll('input+.tab-pane tr:not(:first-child)>td:last-child')
        Array.from(titles).forEach((e) => {
            if (!e.textContent.trim()) {
                e.textContent = '_';
            }
        });
        """
    )

def get_network_data(log: dict, driver: WebDriver) -> dict:
    log = json.loads(log["message"])["message"]
    if all([
        "Network.responseReceived" in log["method"], 
        "params" in log.keys(), 
        'CaptchaAudio' in str(log["params"].values())
        ]):
        return driver.execute_cdp_cmd('Network.getResponseBody', {'requestId': log["params"]["requestId"]})

def get_captcha_text(driver: WebDriver, timeout: float) -> str:
    """Return captcha text

    Arguments:
        - driver: WebDriver
        - timeout: pause before receiving data from the web driver log
    """
    driver.execute_script(
        """
        // document.querySelector('img[title="Captcha"]').click()
        document.querySelector('img[title="Captcha  Audio"]').click()
        """
        )
    sleep(timeout)
    logs = driver.get_log('performance')
    responses = [get_network_data(log, driver) for log in logs if get_network_data(log, driver)]
    if responses:
        return json.loads(responses[0]['body'])['CaptchaImageText']
    else:
        get_captcha_text(driver)

def submit_captcha(captcha_text: str, btn_name: str) -> None:
    """Submit captcha

    Arguments:
        - btn_name: captcha send button name["submit" or "search"]
    """
    if btn_name == 'search':
        captcha_locator = (By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'input[name="submit"]')
    elif btn_name == 'submit':
        captcha_locator = (By.ID, 'btnSubmit')
    wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, 'CaptchaText'))).send_keys(captcha_text)
    wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located(captcha_locator)).click()


# options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
# options.add_argument('--headless')
# options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation", "enable-logging"])
# capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.CHROME
# capabilities["goog:loggingPrefs"] = {"performance": "ALL"}
# service = Service(executable_path="path/to/your/chromedriver.exe")
# # driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options, desired_capabilities=capabilities)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 15)

table_values_locator = (By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'input+.tab-pane tr:not(:first-child)>td:last-child')
applicant_name_locator = (By.ID, 'TextField6')
page_number_locator = (By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'span.Selected')
app_satus_locator = (By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'button.btn')
next_btn_locator = (By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'button.next')

driver.get('https://ipindiaservices.gov.in/PublicSearch/')

# sometimes an alert with an error message("") may appear, so a small pause is used
sleep(1)
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located(applicant_name_locator)).send_keys('ltd')
# on the start page and the page with the table, the names of the buttons are different
captcha_text = get_captcha_text(driver, 1)
submit_captcha(captcha_text, "search")
# the page where the search starts
start_from_page(1, driver)

while True:
    start = time()
    # get current page number
    current_page = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located(page_number_locator)).text
    print(f"Current page: {current_page}")
    # get all application status WebElements
    app_status_elements = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located(app_satus_locator))

    for element in range(len(app_status_elements)):
        print(f"App number: {element}")
        # update application status WebElements
        app_status_elements = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located(app_satus_locator))
        # click on application status
        wait.until(EC.visibility_of(app_status_elements[element])).click()
        # wait 2 seconds for the captcha to change
        sleep(2)
        # get text and submit captcha
        captcha_text = get_captcha_text(driver, 1)
        submit_captcha(captcha_text, "submit")
        try:
            # get all table data values(without titles) WebElements
            table_data_values = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located(table_values_locator))
            # if there are empty rows in the table replace them with "_"
            titles_validation(driver)
            # save data to csv
            save_to_csv([val.text.replace('\n', ' ') for val in table_data_values])
        except TimeoutException:
            print("Application Number does not exist")
        finally:
            driver.back()
    # print the current page number to the console
    print(f"Time per page: {round(time()-start, 3)}")
    # if the current page is equal to the specified one, then stop the search and close the driver
    if current_page == '3776':
        break
    # click next page
    wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located(next_btn_locator)).click()

driver.quit()
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On this site, captcha can be solved without resorting to third-party services. When you click on the "Captcha Audio" button, a GET request is sent to the endpoint `https://ipindiaservices.gov.in/PublicSearch/Captcha/CaptchaAudio` The response is a dictionary `{"CaptchaImageText":"hnnxd"}` which you can access get from Selenium via the `"Chrome Devtools Protocol"` using the `Network.getResponseBody` method, or you can use the `requests` library.
To save data in csv, you can use, for example, the csv module included in the standard library.

Here is one possible solution:

```py
import re
import csv
import json
from time import sleep
from selenium import webdriver
from typing import Generator, List, Tuple
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver import DesiredCapabilities
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.webdriver import WebDriver
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


def get_captcha_text(log: dict, driver: WebDriver) -> dict:
    log = json.loads(log["message"])["message"]
    if all([
        "Network.responseReceived" in log["method"], 
        "params" in log.keys(), 
        'CaptchaAudio' in str(log["params"].values())
        ]):
        return driver.execute_cdp_cmd('Network.getResponseBody', {'requestId': log["params"]["requestId"]})

def save_to_csv(table_data: Generator[None, None, List[Tuple[str, str, str, str]]]) -> None:
    for app_num, title, app_date, status in zip(*list(zip(*table_data))):
        data = {
            'Application Number': app_num,
            'Title': title,
            'Application Date': app_date,
            'Status': status
        }
        with open(file='ipindiaservices.csv', mode='a', encoding="utf-8") as f:
            writer = csv.writer(f, lineterminator='\n')
            writer.writerow([data['Application Number'], data['Title'], data['Application Date'], data['Status']])

def start_from_page(page_number: int, driver: WebDriver) -> None:
    driver.execute_script(
    f"""
    document.querySelector('button.next').value = {page_number}; 
    document.querySelector('button.next').click();
    """
    )

def titles_validation(driver: WebDriver) -> None:
    """replace empty title name with '_'"""
    driver.execute_script(
        """
        let titles = document.querySelectorAll('#tableData>tbody>tr>td.title')
        Array.from(titles).forEach((e) => {
            if (!e.textContent.trim()) {
                e.textContent = '_';
            }
        });
        """
    )

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation", "enable-logging"])
capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.CHROME
capabilities["goog:loggingPrefs"] = {"performance": "ALL"}
service = Service(executable_path="path/to/your/chromedriver.exe")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options, desired_capabilities=capabilities)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

# regular expression to search for data in a table
pattern = r'^([0-9A-Z\/\-,]+) (.+)? ([0-9\/]+) (\w+)'

driver.get('https://ipindiaservices.gov.in/PublicSearch/')

# sometimes an alert with an error message("") may appear, so a small pause is used
sleep(1)
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'img[title="Captcha  Audio"]').click()
driver.find_element(By.ID, 'TextField6').send_keys('ltd')
# short pause is needed here to write the log, otherwise we will get an empty list
sleep(1)
logs = driver.get_log('performance')
# get request data that is generated when click on the button listen to the text of the captcha
responses = [get_captcha_text(log, driver) for log in logs if get_captcha_text(log, driver)]
# get captcha text
captcha_text = json.loads(responses[0]['body'])['CaptchaImageText']
# enter the captcha text and click "Search" button
driver.find_element(By.ID, 'CaptchaText').send_keys(captcha_text)
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'input[name="submit"]').click()

# the page where the search starts
start_from_page(1, driver)

while True:
    # get current page number
    current_page = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'span.Selected'))).text
    # print the current page number to the console
    print(f"Current page: {current_page}")
    # get all fields of the table
    table_web_elements = wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#tableData>tbody>tr')))
    # check title name
    titles_validation(driver)
    # get all table data on current page
    table_data = (re.findall(pattern, data.text)[0] for data in table_web_elements)
    # save table data to csv
    save_to_csv(table_data)
    # if the current page is equal to the specified one, then stop the search and close the driver
    if current_page == '3768':
        break
    # click next page
    driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'button.next').click()

driver.quit()
```

The performance of this solution is about 280sec per 100 pages.

It will take about 2.5-3 hours to collect all the data.

Therefore, the ability to stop data collection on a specific page has been added (by default, this is the last page):

```
if current_page == '3768':
     break
```

And start collection data from the specified page (by default, this is the first page):

```
start_from_page(1, driver)
```

Output is `ipindiaservices.csv`

```
202247057786,NON-AQUEOUS ELECTROLYTE SECONDARY BATTERY,10/10/2022,Published
202247057932,"COMMUNICATION METHOD, APPARATUS AND SYSTEM",10/10/2022,Published
202247057855,POLYOLEFIN RESIN FILM,10/10/2022,Published
202247057853,CEMENT COMPOSITION AND CURED PRODUCT THEREOF,10/10/2022,Published
...
```

To use this solution in `Google Collab`, follow these steps:

1. Install Selenium and ChromeDriver

```
!pip install selenium
!apt-get update
!apt install chromium-chromedriver
```

2. Make the necessary imports

```
import re
import csv
import json
from time import sleep
from typing import Generator, List, Tuple
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver import DesiredCapabilities
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.webdriver import WebDriver
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

3. Set options

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.CHROME
capabilities["goog:loggingPrefs"] = {"performance": "ALL"}
driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver', chrome_options=options, desired_capabilities=capabilities)
```

Everything else remains unchanged.
And don't put all the code in one cell.

**Update**:
This is one possible solution to collect all the information from the table of each application:

```py
import csv
import json
from time import sleep, time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver import DesiredCapabilities
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.webdriver import WebDriver
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException


def save_to_csv(data: list) -> None:
    with open(file='ipindiaservices.csv', mode='a', encoding="utf-8") as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f, lineterminator='\n')
        writer.writerow([*data])

def start_from_page(page_number: int, driver: WebDriver) -> None:
    driver.execute_script(
    f"""
    document.querySelector('button.next').value = {page_number}; 
    document.querySelector('button.next').click();
    """
    )

def titles_validation(driver: WebDriver) -> None:
    """replace empty title name with '_'"""
    driver.execute_script(
        """
        let titles = document.querySelectorAll('input+.tab-pane tr:not(:first-child)>td:last-child')
        Array.from(titles).forEach((e) => {
            if (!e.textContent.trim()) {
                e.textContent = '_';
            }
        });
        """
    )

def get_network_data(log: dict, driver: WebDriver) -> dict:
    log = json.loads(log["message"])["message"]
    if all([
        "Network.responseReceived" in log["method"], 
        "params" in log.keys(), 
        'CaptchaAudio' in str(log["params"].values())
        ]):
        return driver.execute_cdp_cmd('Network.getResponseBody', {'requestId': log["params"]["requestId"]})

def get_captcha_text(driver: WebDriver, timeout: float) -> str:
    """Return captcha text

    Arguments:
        - driver: WebDriver
        - timeout: pause before receiving data from the web driver log
    """
    driver.execute_script(
        """
        // document.querySelector('img[title="Captcha"]').click()
        document.querySelector('img[title="Captcha  Audio"]').click()
        """
        )
    sleep(timeout)
    logs = driver.get_log('performance')
    if responses := [get_network_data(log, driver) for log in logs if get_network_data(log, driver)]:
        return json.loads(responses[0]['body'])['CaptchaImageText']
    else:
        get_captcha_text(driver, timeout)

def submit_captcha(captcha_text: str, btn_name: str) -> None:
    """Submit captcha

    Arguments:
        - btn_name: captcha send button name["submit" or "search"]
    """
    if btn_name == 'search':
        captcha_locator = (By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'input[name="submit"]')
    elif btn_name == 'submit':
        captcha_locator = (By.ID, 'btnSubmit')
    wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, 'CaptchaText'))).send_keys(captcha_text)
    wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located(captcha_locator)).click()


options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation", "enable-logging"])
capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.CHROME
capabilities["goog:loggingPrefs"] = {"performance": "ALL"}
service = Service(executable_path="path/to/your/chromedriver.exe")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options, desired_capabilities=capabilities)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 15)

table_values_locator = (By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'input+.tab-pane tr:not(:first-child)>td:last-child')
applicant_name_locator = (By.ID, 'TextField6')
page_number_locator = (By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'span.Selected')
app_satus_locator = (By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'button.btn')
next_btn_locator = (By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'button.next')

driver.get('https://ipindiaservices.gov.in/PublicSearch/')

# sometimes an alert with an error message("") may appear, so a small pause is used
sleep(1)
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located(applicant_name_locator)).send_keys('ltd')
# on the start page and the page with the table, the names of the buttons are different
captcha_text = get_captcha_text(driver, 1)
submit_captcha(captcha_text, "search")
# the page where the search starts
start_from_page(1, driver)

while True:
    start = time()
    # get current page number
    current_page = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located(page_number_locator)).text
    print(f"Current page: {current_page}")
    # get all application status WebElements
    app_status_elements = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located(app_satus_locator))

    for element in range(len(app_status_elements)):
        print(f"App number: {element}")
        # update application status WebElements
        app_status_elements = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located(app_satus_locator))
        # click on application status
        wait.until(EC.visibility_of(app_status_elements[element])).click()
        # wait 2 seconds for the captcha to change
        sleep(2)
        # get text and submit captcha
        captcha_text = get_captcha_text(driver, 1)
        submit_captcha(captcha_text, "submit")
        try:
            # get all table data values(without titles) WebElements
            table_data_values = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located(table_values_locator))
            # if there are empty rows in the table replace them with "_"
            titles_validation(driver)
            # save data to csv
            save_to_csv([val.text.replace('\n', ' ') for val in table_data_values])
        except TimeoutException:
            print("Application Number does not exist")
        finally:
            driver.back()
    # print the current page number to the console
    print(f"Time per page: {round(time()-start, 3)}")
    # if the current page is equal to the specified one, then stop the search and close the driver
    if current_page == '3776':
        break
    # click next page
    wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located(next_btn_locator)).click()

driver.quit()
```

Output is `ipindiaservices.csv`

```
202247059447,PCT NATIONAL PHASE APPLICATION,18/10/2022,"PANASONIC INTELLECTUAL PROPERTY MANAGEMENT CO., LTD.",SOLID ELECTROLYTE MATERIAL AND BATTERY USING SAME,ELECTRICAL,patent@depenning.com,_,_,PCT/JP2021/004427,05/02/2021,31/03/2020,--,21/10/2022
202247059470,PCT NATIONAL PHASE APPLICATION,18/10/2022,"SHENZHEN SKYWORTH-RGB ELECTRONIC CO., LTD.","ATTACHMENT FORCE ADJUSTMENT METHOD AND APPARATUS, DEVICE, AND STORAGE MEDIUM",COMPUTER SCIENCE,ipo@knspartners.com,_,_,PCT/CN2020/125555,30/10/2020,02/04/2020,18/10/2022,21/10/2022
202247058733,PCT NATIONAL PHASE APPLICATION,14/10/2022,"SUMITOMO ELECTRIC OPTIFRONTIER CO., LTD.","FUSION SPLICING SYSTEM, FUSION SPLICING DEVICE, AND DETERIORATION DETERMINATION METHOD",COMPUTER SCIENCE,patent@depenning.com,_,_,PCT/JP2021/017016,28/04/2021,30/04/2020,--,21/10/2022
```

The performance of this solution is about `230sec` per page.

Sometimes there may be no data on the aplication status page (for example, by the number "00054/CAL/1998" we get "Application Number does not exist") Therefore, the script simply ignores this aplication.

`2 sec timeout before receiving the captcha text is due to the fact that after clicking on "Application Status" one captcha is shown and after ~1sec it changes to another one which we must enter`

**Fix**:
Since the captcha that appeared after clicking on `Application status` was removed from the site, its solution from the script was also removed. Also, the developers of this resource made the same classes for `Application Number` and `Application status`, so we needed to change the css selector for `Application status`.
Solution for `Google Colab`:

```
import csv
import json
from time import sleep, time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver import DesiredCapabilities
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.webdriver import WebDriver
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException


def save_to_csv(data: list) -> None:
    with open(file='ipindiaservices.csv', mode='a', encoding="utf-8") as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f, lineterminator='\n')
        writer.writerow([*data])

def start_from_page(page_number: int, driver: WebDriver) -> None:
    driver.execute_script(
    f"""
    document.querySelector('button.next').value = {page_number}; 
    document.querySelector('button.next').click();
    """
    )

def titles_validation(driver: WebDriver) -> None:
    """replace empty title name with '_'"""
    driver.execute_script(
        """
        let titles = document.querySelectorAll('input+.tab-pane tr:not(:first-child)>td:last-child')
        Array.from(titles).forEach((e) => {
            if (!e.textContent.trim()) {
                e.textContent = '_';
            }
        });
        """
    )

def get_network_data(log: dict, driver: WebDriver) -> dict:
    log = json.loads(log["message"])["message"]
    if all([
        "Network.responseReceived" in log["method"], 
        "params" in log.keys(), 
        'CaptchaAudio' in str(log["params"].values())
        ]):
        return driver.execute_cdp_cmd('Network.getResponseBody', {'requestId': log["params"]["requestId"]})

def get_captcha_text(driver: WebDriver, timeout: float) -> str:
    """Return captcha text

    Arguments:
        - driver: WebDriver
        - timeout: pause before receiving data from the web driver log
    """
    driver.execute_script(
        """
        // document.querySelector('img[title="Captcha"]').click()
        document.querySelector('img[title="Captcha  Audio"]').click()
        """
        )
    sleep(timeout)
    logs = driver.get_log('performance')
    responses = [get_network_data(log, driver) for log in logs if get_network_data(log, driver)]
    if responses:
        return json.loads(responses[0]['body'])['CaptchaImageText']
    else:
        get_captcha_text(driver, timeout)

def submit_captcha(captcha_text: str, btn_name: str) -> None:
    """Submit captcha

    Arguments:
        - btn_name: captcha send button name["submit" or "search"]
    """
    if btn_name == 'search':
        captcha_locator = (By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'input[name="submit"]')
    elif btn_name == 'submit':
        captcha_locator = (By.ID, 'btnSubmit')
    wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, 'CaptchaText'))).send_keys(captcha_text)
    wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located(captcha_locator)).click()


options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation", "enable-logging"])
capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.CHROME
capabilities["goog:loggingPrefs"] = {"performance": "ALL"}
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='chromedriver', options=options, desired_capabilities=capabilities)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

table_values_locator = (By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'input+.tab-pane tr:not(:first-child)>td:last-child')
applicant_name_locator = (By.ID, 'TextField6')
page_number_locator = (By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'span.Selected')
app_satus_locator = (By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'button[name="ApplicationSatus"]')
next_btn_locator = (By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'button.next')

driver.get('https://ipindiaservices.gov.in/PublicSearch/')

# sometimes an alert with an error message("") may appear, so a small pause is used
sleep(1)
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located(applicant_name_locator)).send_keys('ltd')
# on the start page and the page with the table, the names of the buttons are different
captcha_text = get_captcha_text(driver, 1)
submit_captcha(captcha_text, "search")
# the page where the search starts
start_from_page(1, driver)

while True:
    start = time()
    # get current page number
    current_page = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located(page_number_locator)).text
    print(f"Current page: {current_page}")
    # get all application status WebElements
    app_status_elements = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located(app_satus_locator))

    for element in range(len(app_status_elements)):
        print(f"App number: {element}")
        # update application status WebElements
        app_status_elements = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located(app_satus_locator))
        # click on application status
        wait.until(EC.visibility_of(app_status_elements[element])).click()
        try:
            # switch to new tab
            driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[-1])
            # get all table data values(without titles) WebElements
            table_data_values = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located(table_values_locator))
            # if there are empty rows in the table replace them with "_"
            titles_validation(driver)
            # save data to csv
            save_to_csv([val.text.replace('\n', ' ') for val in table_data_values])
        except TimeoutException:
            print("Application Number does not exist")
        finally:
            # close new tab
            driver.close()
            # switch to main tab
            driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[0])
    # print the current page number to the console
    print(f"Time per page: {round(time()-start, 3)}")
    # if the current page is equal to the specified one, then stop the search and close the driver
    if current_page == '100':
        break
    # click next page
    wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located(next_btn_locator)).click()

driver.quit()
```

These fixes have been tested on `Google Colab`(python 3.7.15).
The performance of this solution is about `55sec` per page.

Previous versions of script are left for visual comparison.

Comment: Thanks! @Brze Getting error as attached!

Comment: @XYZ add `from typing import Generator, List, Tuple` and change to `def save_to_csv(table_data: Generator[None, None, List[Tuple[str, str, str, str]]]) -> None:`. This occurs on python 3.9 and below due to the fact that list[tuple[str, str, str, str]] is attempting to subscript the object list

Comment: I am not able to resolve this. Not getting why this is throwing an error

Comment: @XYZ You didn't mention anywhere that you use colab. In order to use selenium in this environment you need to install it, this is done like this: `!pip install selenium
!apt-get update !apt install chromium-chromedriver` you will also need to add a few options: `options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')`


I'll update the answer to make it clear to you.

Comment: That will be a great help, if you can please comment in the code ,I am learning a lot from your super clean code

Comment: Thanks a ton! Trying to understand this code line by line.

Comment: I have updated the question. Seeing your code, I have got a little idea,can u help me modifying your code to get the final extraction?

Comment: @XYZ updated the answer, this solution ran on python 3.9.10. But now you know how to set up and run Selenium in Google Colab.

Comment: I have edited the answer, Can you please check?

Comment: Also I think  ---  name 'responses' is not defined in your updated code

Comment: @XYZ as I wrote, I ran this solution on python 3.9.10 but since you are using Google Colab (python 3.8 is used in this environment) you must replace the walrus operator `:=` with `if responses: return json.loads(responses[0]['body'])['CaptchaImageText'] else: get_captcha_text(driver, timeout)`

Comment: Ok, I have recently checked the version. It is Python 3.7.15

Comment: @XYZ  I have now run this solution in Colab and it works OK. Just remove walrus operator(`:=`) as it is not supported by version 3.7

Comment: what operator will be in place of the walrus?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249143/discussion-between-brze-and-xyz).

Comment: this entire code is not working now! IDK why :(

Comment: @XYZ The developers of this resource have made some changes. See updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use any capctha solving sites. On these sites, users usually fix it themselves, so they can be slow, but it does the job.

[Sample website (I didn't receive any ads)](https://2captcha.com/)

You can use [selenium](https://pypi.org/project/selenium/) to pull the information. It will be enough to take and place the elements with the "id" tag on the site.
[Library for reading/writing excel in python](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)